# Gmail API no longer returns Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: gmail-api, response-headers

We're using the **Gmail API** to enable users to send emails from our app.

The following request (with `uploadType=resumable` included) has been working well till yesterday,

`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send&uploadType=resumable`

but suddenly it no longer returns the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response, leading to a CORS error.

Has Google changed its policy recently? Or, can anybody guess what might have caused this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's a bug

Many users are affected by it.

It has already been filed on Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/157312473).

I recommend you to give the issue a "star" to highlight the importance and increase visibility.